# Boxplot from a table of values in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, boxplot

I have a dataframe that has values of the year, passenger data and the country its from. The country remains the same thought out the dataframe.

I'm trying to plot a boxplot. Where the country: "USA" is on the x axis and the passenger data for all the years in displayed on the y axis.

but I get: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'boxplot'

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('CityPairs.csv')

filt = (df.Country == 'USA')
df = df[filt]
reqcol = ['Year', 'Country', 'Passengers_Total']
df = df[reqcol]

groupbyCountry = df.groupby(['Year', 'Country'])['Passengers_Total'].sum()
groupbyCountry

groupbyCountry.boxplot(column = 'Passengers_Total', by = 'Country')
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) or parameter `as_index=True` for `DataFrame`:

```
groupbyCountry = df.groupby(['Year', 'Country'])['Passengers_Total'].sum().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
groupbyCountry = df.groupby(['Year', 'Country'], as_index=False)['Passengers_Total'].sum()
```

If ploting only one category (`USA`) you can code simplify:

```
groupbyCountry.boxplot(column = 'Passengers_Total')
```

Comment: That seems to have done it! ill tick it when the timers done, cheers!